# Lost Qt Key Events when window focus changes

Tags: qt

I have installed a QApplication event filter to handle QKeyEvents.  When certain key presses are delivered to any of a set of (parentless) windows, the window loses focus, is disabled using QWidget::setEnabled(false), and another window is opened.  The problem I see is that key events delivered after the first window loses focus but before the second window gains focus are lost, as in not delivered to the event filter.  Does anyone know where the missing events go?  I'm using Qt 4.1.4

Comment: Try it in latest Qt 4.7 or 4.8 and see if you can still reproduce the issue.

Comment: Does your application have any open windows during that time? Could it be that your application does not have focus at all and that's why it does not get any key events? Could you open the new window first and give it the focus and after that close the first window ?

Comment: The first window persists in the background and focus may need to be restored later, but in the multi-threaded environment there has to be a brief period where neither of the two threads being used here has a window in focus.  Taking out the setEnabled(false) on losing focus, the keyEvents are still seen to be delivered despite this temporary lack of focus, which implies Qt is not directing events solely on focus.  I am trying to work out what is responsible for this direction, and if the key events can be obtained somehow.